# Calling External Library function inside VueJS

Tags: javascript, function, vue.js, call, external

I have searched around but didn't find a working example of how this is done. Basically, I am trying to connect an external JS file (written in JS) and trying to call its function using this.

```
<script src="/static/medium-editor.min.js"></script>

<script>


export default {
name: 'App',

mounted: function() {
    var editor = new MediumEditor('.editable', {
        toolbar: {
            buttons: ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'anchor']
        }
    });
    console.log('testing...')
}

}
</script>
```

The file seems to be loading fine but I get this error

```
ReferenceError: MediumEditor is not defined
```

I have also tried to use import MediumEditor but I think we have to export it in the other js file which doesn't work as well.

For reference, I am trying to add this plugin to my vuejs test project: https://github.com/yabwe/medium-editor/blob/master/dist/js/medium-editor.js

If anyone has any idea on how we can call that external function within VueJS and make it work, I will be very grateful. I am a beginner but I have searched the whole day and haven't found a similar solution.

Thanks in advance

Chandra

**Update**: Added a JSFiddle, if you want to try: https://jsfiddle.net/maharzan/nze45uxf/2/

Comment: I added the js link to index.html and I do not see any error but the editor is not coming to effect.

Comment: If you have installed it via npm, you can import it like `import MediumEditor from 'medium-editor'`. Then use MediumEditor variable for processing.

Comment: I did that but it gives another error. `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#<Object>'`

Comment: Here is the JSFiddle, if you can make it work: https://jsfiddle.net/maharzan/nze45uxf/2/

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to import the file using the `script` tag do it using `import` statement.

```
<script>

    import MediumEditor from '/static/medium-editor.min.js'

    export default {
        name: 'App',

        mounted: function() {
            var editor = new MediumEditor('.editable', {
                toolbar: {
                buttons: ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'anchor']
            });
            console.log('testing...')
        }
    }

</script>
```

#### Update:-

if you export the function using `module.exports` then importing it using `import` statements gives you the error `Cannot assign to read-only property 'exports' of object '#<Object>`. To prevent it export the function using `export default`.

See this:- https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4039

Comment: I did that too but it gives another error. `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#<Object>'` Definitely something on that min.js file needs to be edited, not sure what.

Comment: did you do `module.exports` or `export default` on that function?

Comment: I think there is a problem because you would have exported the function using `module.exports` and importing using `import` statement.

Comment: I did that but not sure exactly what the code should be. Can you check this file and see what needs to be added? https://github.com/yabwe/medium-editor/blob/master/dist/js/medium-editor.js Apparently, found out module.exports doesn't work. I did try `export default { MediumEditor; }` but didn't work.

Comment: try `export default MediumEditor`

Comment: still get this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#<Object>'`

Comment: I added it to the end of medium-editor.min.js file `export default MediumEditor;` What am I missing?

Comment: **Added a jsfiddle: ** https://jsfiddle.net/maharzan/nze45uxf/2/ Please check how can we fix that undefined object.